# Apache not start/restart

Tags: server, apache2

I'm having problems with Apache on Ubuntu 15.10. When I run `sudo service apache2 restart`

The following error appear:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I run `systemctl status apache2.service`

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sex 2016-01-08 09:05:40 BRST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5840 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: * Starting web server apache2
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: *
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: Output of config test was:
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: chown: invalid user: 'victor'
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And `journalctl -xe`

```
Jan 08 09:09:09 marcelonote dbus[621]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' (using servicehelper)
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon[6017]: INFO: Initializing daemon
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.PackageKit[6017]: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote dbus[621]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.PackageKit[6017]: INFO: CreateTransaction() was called
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: CreateTransaction() was called
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.PackageKit[6017]: INFO: Initializing PackageKit transaction
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: Initializing PackageKit transaction
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.PackageKit[6017]: INFO: GetUpdates() was called
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: GetUpdates() was called
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.Worker[6017]: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/e86dea17ca9e4f5e9ecfa4703b955c61
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/e8
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote AptDaemon.Worker[6017]: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e86dea17ca9e4f5e9ecfa4703b955c61
Jan 08 09:09:10 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:10 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transacti
Jan 08 09:09:13 marcelonote AptDaemon.Worker[6017]: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e86dea17ca9e4f5e9ecfa4703b955c61
Jan 08 09:09:13 marcelonote org.freedesktop.PackageKit[621]: 09:09:13 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction
Jan 08 09:10:07 marcelonote upowerd[1569]: (upowerd:1569): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: energy 26,833560 bigger than full 26,757575
Jan 08 09:12:07 marcelonote upowerd[1569]: (upowerd:1569): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: energy 26,920400 bigger than full 26,833560
Jan 08 09:12:22 marcelonote systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
```

I try to reinstall apache, but the problem persists.

Running `grep victor /etc/apache2 -R`

```
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_USER=victor
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=victor
```

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `grep victor /etc/apache2 -R`

Comment: @muru Post the output

Comment: Now why do you have those two lines in `envvars`?

Comment: I don't know. Should I delete these lines or change 'victor' for my username?

Comment: They shouldn't be victor or your username, they should be `www-data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log shows this: 
`Jan 08 09:05:40 marcelonote apache2[5840]: chown: invalid user: 'victor'`

It seems that there is no such user called victor. 
Change your `/etc/apache2/envvars` `APACHE_RUN_USER` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` to `www-data` and restart the apache again.

Comment: Made the changes and now the error is: apache2: Could not open configura...y. I believe I delete some files from apache2 folder. How can I get theses files again?

Comment: If you don't have any important configuration files from `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/` , then you can purge your apache2 and then install it again by : `apt-get remove --purge apache2 && apt-get install apache2`

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this, and enter this from the terminal:

```
 cron apache2
 cron restart
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: When I run the first command:  cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 616: Resource temporarily unavailable